# Getting a StackOverflowError when trying to fetch a object from database

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

This is my entity class

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "wishlist")
public class Wishlist {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Customer.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false,name = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;

    @Column(name = "created_date")
    private Date createdDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Products product;

    public Wishlist(Customer customer, Products product) {
        this.customer = customer;
        this.createdDate = new Date();
        this.product = product;
    }
    
    public Wishlist() {
        
    }
}
```

This my repository

```
public interface WishlistRepository extends JpaRepository<Wishlist, Integer> {
    List<Wishlist> findAllByCustomerIdOrderByCreatedDateDesc(Integer customerId);
    Optional<Wishlist> findByProductId(Integer productId);
}
```

This my service layer

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class WishlistServiceImpl implements WishlistService{

    @Autowired
    WishlistRepository wishlistRepo;

    @Override
    public void createWishlist(Wishlist wishlist,Integer productId) throws ProductNotExistsException {
        Optional<Wishlist> optionalProduct = wishlistRepo.findByProductId(productId);
        System.out.println(optionalProduct)
    }
}
```

So I am trying to check if the product is present on my wishlist or not using product id.

But getting the error:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.putStringAt(AbstractStringBuilder.java:1720) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.putStringAt(AbstractStringBuilder.java:1724) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:583) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:175) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:87) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.<init>(AbstractStringBuilder.java:112) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>(StringBuilder.java:127) ~[na:na]
    at com.ecommerce.entity.Customer.toString(Customer.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
```

So how to solve this issue?

Comment: Show us your toString() method of Customer, Product and Wishlist.

Comment: For Customer, Product & Wishlist I am using @Data

Comment: Don't use @Data with JPA entities because toString equals and hashCode will produce this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a circular dependency between product and wishlist.

@Data bundles the features of @ToString , @EqualsAndHashCode , @Getter / @Setter and @RequiredArgsConstructor together.

You can either exclude fields from hashcode and equals with @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude (See more information in [enter link description here](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode) or you can replace @Data with @Getter and @Setter.

Answer (score 0):

might be the issue with the cyclic dependencies.

try adding the following annotation:

```
@ToString.Exclude
```

or
try to override the toString implementation.

Comment: Particulary where should I give the annotation

Comment: @PritamDas in your entity classes in this case or you can override the toString() method with your own implementation.